# Transfer music from iphone to ubuntu

Tags: music, iphone, transfer

Ive got an iPhone 5 running iOS 7. I want to transfer the music from the iphone to my Ubuntu and be able to play them locally on my computer without plugging in my iPhone.

**So, the simple question is, is it possible to tranfer music from iOS 7.1 to Ubuntu 14.04 running devices**(and I know that apple wont probably like me to)**?**

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](http://ipod.about.com/od/advanceditunesuse/f/Downloading-Itunes-For-Linux.htm). It will help install iTunes in Ubuntu via a program called Wine.